# Why is sizeof(T) different inside my container allocator than in the allocator alone?

Tags: c++, containers, sizeof, pool, allocator

In this code, I get a different sizeof(T) if the allocator
 is part of a container allocation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <cstddef>


class Item
{
    int a;
    unsigned char b, c, d;
    int e, f, g;

  public:
    Item() { a = b = c = d = e = f = g = 0; }
    bool operator<(const Item& item) const { return item.a < a; }
};

template <typename T> class TestAllocator
{
  public:
    typedef T         value_type;
    typedef size_t    size_type;
    typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;

    typedef T*        pointer;
    typedef const T*  const_pointer;

    typedef T&        reference;
    typedef const T&  const_reference;

    pointer address(reference x) const { return &x; }
    const_pointer address(const_reference x) const { return &x; }

    TestAllocator() { std::cout << "TestAllocator ctor: sizeof T:" << sizeof(T) << std::endl; }

    template <typename U> TestAllocator(const TestAllocator<U>&) {}
    ~TestAllocator() {}

    pointer allocate(size_type /*n*/, void * = 0) { return static_cast<T*>(new T()); }

    void deallocate(pointer p, size_type /*n*/) { delete p; }

    TestAllocator<T>&  operator=(const TestAllocator&) { return *this; }
    void construct(pointer p, const T& val) { new ((T*) p) T(val); }
    void destroy(pointer p) { p->~T(); }
    size_type max_size() const { return size_t(-1); }

    template <typename U> struct rebind { typedef TestAllocator<U> other; };
    template <typename U> TestAllocator& operator=(const TestAllocator<U>&) { return *this; }
};


typedef std::multiset<Item, std::less<Item>, TestAllocator<Item> > ItemMultiset;


int main(int /*argc*/, char** /*argv*/) 
{
  std::cout << "Instantiating allocator:" << std::endl;
  TestAllocator<Item> ta;

  std::cout << "Instantiating container:" << std::endl;
  ItemMultiset ims;

  return 0;
}
```

Here on my gcc 7.2.1, I get:

```
Instantiating allocator:
TestAllocator ctor: sizeof T:20
Instantiating container:
TestAllocator ctor: sizeof T:56
```

Some online compilers results:

VC++ at webcompiler.cloudapp.net said 20 and 36.

Coliru at coliru.stacked-crooked.com said 20 and 56
 for all selected gcc compilers, 20 and 56 for clang 3.8,
 or 20 and 48 for clang 3.8 C++11/14.

Why the difference, and why do some results pad every struct member?

How can I ask what alignment 'mode' the container is in and 
 apply it to my struct or code, or else how can I tell the 
 container to use my code's mode, to ensure the results are
 always identical?

EDIT: Thanks for the fast reply below.

Wow, a lot of space used. Further results with other containers:

```
Instantiating allocator:
TestAllocator ctor: sizeof T:20

Instantiating multiset:
TestAllocator ctor: sizeof T:56

Instantiating multimap:
TestAllocator ctor: sizeof T:20

Instantiating list:
TestAllocator ctor: sizeof T:40

Instantiating vector:
TestAllocator ctor: sizeof T:20
```

EDIT 2:

For the benefit of those working with allocation pools:

Yay! I think I achieved my goal. The sample code is based
 on a real app and, as you might expect, the allocator template's
 `allocate` and `deallocate` don't just call `new` and `delete`.
 they hand off to a pool. Until Thursday the pool was a global
 chunking style multi-dimensional (several different planes
 for common expected size requests). `allocate` would pass 
 the number of bytes required. Then I template-ized our 
 global pool, but somewhat clumsily the global instance had to
 be separately initialized with the desired type - that's where
 the trouble started, that's not the right type! I saw an opportunity 
 for `allocate` to pass only the number of items instead of bytes.
 As you saw it didn't work the way I tried. My mistake was that
 so soon after template-izing our pool, I didn't realize I could
 just drop a static instance of it in my allocator template class.
Boom, problem solved, all the sizeof's are consistent now. The pool
 is working fine now, it is now a template embedded into the
 allocator template class, and it is more lean and efficient than our
 previous version. ~25 years with C++, templates never cease to amaze me. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying the display function to:

```
TestAllocator() { std::cout << "TestAllocator ctor: sizeof T:" << sizeof(T) << " ," << typeid(T).name() << std::endl; }
```

I get output:

```
Instantiating allocator:
TestAllocator ctor: sizeof T:20, 4Item
Instantiating container:
TestAllocator ctor: sizeof T:56, St13_Rb_tree_nodeI4ItemE
```

which should dispel your confusion.  The template type used by the multiset is a node class that itself contains an `Item`.  Checking your implementation's multiset header might help with seeing when the allocators are bound and used.

Comment: Apologies for never returning to choose a correct answer. Hope it's not too late. Thanks to both answers, this one is a little more detailed.

Answer (score 4):

The `multiset` doesn't store `Item`s directly, but uses some tree structure that adds additional pointers to navigate in the tree.

It really uses `TestAllocator<some_internal_node_type>` to allocate objects. And it is the node type's size you get.

Comment: I'd add that this is what the `rebind` member template is for - the container uses that to get from the `TestAllocator<Item>` type to the `TestAllocator<some_internal_node_type>` it actually uses.